# How do I output the locale’s name?

Tags: templating, localization

When I output `{{ craft.locale }}` in my template, I get the current locale’s ID (e.g. “en”) rather than its name (e.g. “English”).

How do I get the locale’s **name**?

Comment: For anyone coming here for `craft.locale`: It's deprecated, use `craft.app.language` now.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can get the current locale’s name via `craft.i18n.getCurrentLocale()`.

```
{% set locale = craft.i18n.getCurrentLocale() %}
{{ locale.name }}
```

That will output the name using the current locale’s translation.

If you would prefer to output the locale’s name in its native tongue, use `nativeName` instead:

```
{{ locale.nativeName }}
```

You can also output the name of any locale using (not necessarily the current one) using `craft.i18n.getLocaleById()`:

```
{% set locale = craft.i18n.getLocaleById(entry.locale) %}
{{ locale.name }}
{{ locale.nativeName }}
```

Comment: Nice Brandon! Can you please add how to access the i18n name for non-current locales? Let's say all I have is a string "de". Thanks

Comment: @ChristianSeelbach updated ;)

Comment: Thanks! I now have to update [this answer](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/882/125) a 6th time ;)