# Get local's URL for index page

Tags: localization

I have two menus.
One with countries, one with navigation.

Navigation menu must to have a index link of a active locale. 
So if I'm at example.com/uk/section and I go to navigation menu and click at index link, I get index of /uk

My countries menu code is:

```
{% set locales = ['en', 'en_gb', 'sk'] %}
    {# Check if locale equals the requested page locale #}
    {% if locale == craft.locale %}
        {% set current = true %}
    {% else %}
        {% set current = false %}
    {% endif %}
    {% set locale = craft.i18n.getCurrentLocale() %}
      {% for locale in locales %}
         <li>
           <a href="{{ craft.config.siteUrl[locale] ~ craft.request.getPath() }}" class="{{ current ? 'uk-active'}}">{{ craft.i18n.getLocaleById(locale).name }}</a></li>
```

When I try to copy

```
<a href="{{ craft.config.siteUrl[locale] ~ craft.request.getPath() }}" 
class="{{ current ? 'uk-active'}}">{{ craft.i18n.getLocaleById(locale).name }}</a>
```

and put it to my navigation menu I get

```
Internal Server Error    array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer
```

Is it fixable or any other way around?

Comment: Does `locale` in line 3 have a value? Code looks like there's missing pieces. See [this question](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/877/125) for a working Language switch solution I use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I probably don't fully understand what you're trying to acchieve, but to get to the index page of your current locale, you'd simply use `siteUrl()`.

Answer (score 2):

When calling this:

```
 {% set locale = craft.i18n.getCurrentLocale() %}
```

`locale` is set to a full blown [LocaleModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/LocaleModel) object.

What you're probably looking for is its [getId()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/LocaleModel#getId-detail) method.

```
craft.config.siteUrl[locale->getId()]
```

Comment: Thanks Brad for your respond and time. To get a index link of a locale was simply to use `siteUrl()`.