# Is it possible to loop through locales?

Tags: localization

Is it possible to loop through locales? For example:

```
{% locale in craft.locales %}
    {# get link for each locale available #}
    <a href="{{ locale.getUrl }}">{{ locale.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use the following code to loop through the locales:

```
{% set locales = craft.i18n.getSiteLocaleIds()%}

{% for locale in locales %}
    {% set localeEntry = craft.entries.id(entry.id).locale(locale).first %}
    <a href="{{ localeEntry.getUrl() }}">{{ localeEntry.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

A full solution for a language switcher is described under [How can I build a language switcher?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/44/how-can-i-build-a-language-switcher)

Comment: I think it's a better idea to define the order manually with a custom array and loop through that. See code here: [How do I create a locale dropdown to switch between languages?](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/877/125)